# How to use Map/Reduce and MongoDB to group by linked document attributes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to figure out a good way to group user site visits by demographic, using MongoDB and Map/Reduce.  I have the following collections:

Site visits - Example:

```
{
    userId: '184792',
    resource: '/example/foo',
    visitTime: ISODate(...)
}
```

User profiles - Example:

```
{
    userId: '184792',
    demo: '18-30',
    city: 'Austin',
    state: 'TX',
    ...
}
```

I wanted to generate a report showing the number of site visits by demographic, either daily or monthly.  However, If I do a Map/Reduce on Site Visits, I only have access to the userId, not the demographic info, so I have no way to emit keys based on the demographic.  In fact, if I wanted to group by any user attribute, such as State, that would also be impossible.

Does anyone know what the best-practices way to solve this problem would be in MongoDB?  Should I duplicate all the user attributes in every Site Visit document?  Should I do some type of re-reduce inside the application code, where I could join the collections using multiple queries?  Or am I just using the wrong tools to solve this type of problem?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` output option to, in effect, merge two map reduce results together.

> { reduce : "collectionName" } - If documents exists for a given key in
>   the result set and in the old collection, then a reduce operation
>   (using the specified reduce function) will be performed on the two
>   values and the result will be written to the output collection. If a
>   finalize function was provided, this will be run after the reduce as
>   well.

You'll need to map both collections to a common format so you can perform this reduce step acting on one document from each source mapped document and merging the appropriate fields from each.

See [this blog entry](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at this option but I wasn't sure I could get the keys to match up to do the join.  After reading that post, I was able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions here:

1. Denormalize the demographic data into the site visits.
2. Do a "client-side" Map/Reduce. i.e.: write a script that loops through the visits, loads the appropriate user profile and then updates a summary collection.
3. Keep real-time counters for this.

> Does anyone know what the best-practices way to solve this problem would be in MongoDB?

With MongoDB, the answer is usually *"it depends"*. And in this case, it really does.

Some questions to consider:

- Are you already looking up the profile data on every visit?
- Do you want the data "real-time"?
- Do you know all of the expected roll-ups in advance?
- Do you want to store all of the transaction data or do you just care about the roll-ups?

**Typically, the solution here is a combination of #1 & #3.**

If you want transaction data and "flexible" reporting, then you'll want to keep the profile data with every visit.

If you know your main reports in advance, then I suggest using some form of counters and writing to these at the same time you write the transactions. So you basically build your report data set on the fly. Yes it's more writes, but MongoDB favors this pattern of doing lots of writes.

Comment: This is a really good answer too.  I was looking more for the re-reduce option, but these are great questions to think about.

Comment: if you like the answer, just hit the upvote button on the left, that will still give me points towards my MongoDB gold badge.